# Battery Status in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, perfmon

I have been creating a winform  application using perfmon. I have found out that the battery status will not work because its part of windows management. So I decide to go the wmi route.

So my question is when I put the battery status in a label as shown below:

```
private void BatteryStatus()
    {
        System.Management.ManagementClass wmi  = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
        var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();

        foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
        {
            int estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
            if (estimatedChargeRemaining == 100)
            {
                label13.Text = "Remaining:" + "  " + estimatedChargeRemaining + "  " + "%";
            }
        }



    }
```

The charge remaining is shown perfectly. My question is, is there a way that I can have just one `if statement` to call the battery status from 100 to 1

or the way I am doing it will I have to do 99 more `if statements`?

this is part of my performance monitor I am custom building. It would be easier if perfmon would allow the counter. This is the only way I can think of to get the battery stats such as:

```
Charge Rate
Discharge Rate
Remaining Capacity
Voltage
```

I have always did `if statements` with the labels on battery status. Before I go into doing 99 more `if statements` I want to be sure there is not an easier way?

*********** Update ************
I figured it out. Thanks for the help for the ones who helped.

Comment: Why do you think that you need and if?

Comment: I have always used `if statements` on labels. I have never been shown any other way and most examples I have researched does it with `if statements` and for the past 5 years I have done it this way. I am wondering if there is an easier way

Comment: There's really no reason for an `if` statement at all, here... unless you're calling `BatteryStatus` under specific circumstances (that I can't even fathom).

Comment: Furthermore, the logic is problematic when you have more than one battery.  You're only going to get the remaining charge left on the **very last battery** in the list.

Comment: I just did `label13.Text = estimatedChargeRemaining.ToString();` and it works. However I figured this would cause a problem say when the battery gets to 10% then how would I change the text of 10% to red with out using `if statements`

Comment: as far as I am aware I have to use `if statements` to change the text color at certain intervals. Unless I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing that what you want to do is this:

```
private void BatteryStatus()
{
    System.Management.ManagementClass wmi  = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
    var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();

    foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
    {
        int estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);           
        label13.Text = "Remaining:" + "  " + estimatedChargeRemaining + "  " + "%";
    }
}
```

No need for and `if` statment, the label will be updated no matter what the percentage is.

On the second part of the question you say that you want to show the "battery status", you can then use `if` like this:

```
  private void BatteryStatus()
 {
    System.Management.ManagementClass wmi  = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
    var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();

    foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
    {
        int estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]); 
        string Status = "";    
        if(estimatedChargeRemaining < 15) Status = "Critical";
        else  if(estimatedChargeRemaining < 35) Status = "Low";
        else  if(estimatedChargeRemaining < 60) Status = "Regular";
        else  if(estimatedChargeRemaining < 90) Status = "High";
        else Status = "Complete";

        label13.Text = "Remaining:" + "  " + estimatedChargeRemaining + "  " + "% | Status: " + Status;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok doing it  `label13.Text = estimatedChargeRemaining.ToString();` I could use the `label13.ForeColor = Color.Red; ` but use it as an if statement

Comment: Wouldn't this code, and other posts and OP, only return the data from the last battery in `allBatteries`. BTW a Case statement would be an easy code approach for multiple levels.

Comment: It would, but what kind of device has mutiple batteries? Probably there mothod returns an array of 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void BatteryStatus()
    {
        System.Management.ManagementClass wmi  = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
        var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();

        foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
        {
            int estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
            label13.Text = "Remaining" + "  " + estimatedChargeRemaining.ToString() + "  " + "%";
            if (estimatedChargeRemaining < 15 )
            {
                label13.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }



    }
```